# Dense layer using Keras with Theano

Tags: python-2.7, keras, theano

I am starting a simple tutorial in keras. The full code I am using is at the end of this website:

```
https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: ('The specified size contains a dimension with value <= 0', (-768, 128))
```

for the lines where Dense appears:

```
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
```

and

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I am using this json file for the backend configuration:

```
{
"image_dim_ordering": "tf",
"epsilon": 1e-07, 
"floatx": "float32", 
"backend": "theano"
}
```

Any idea on what is the problem? I am using python2.7 and the MNIST database seems to be right since I was able to plot the images and also to see the labels with no problem.

Best,

Ángel.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `"image_dim_ordering": "tf"` to `"image_dim_ordering": "th"`, since you're using Theano as your backend.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess that that was one error in what I was doing. I edited the json file with that change but it does not work. I am getting the same error.

Comment: I think the error is in this line: " model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))" probably due to the sintaxis. I had to edit a couple of lines to match with the keras version that I have installed, that is not the same of the official documentation. For instance, the line "model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))" was changed to "model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))" with the parenthesis. I think something similar is happening with "Dense"...